# how to convert 12 hours timestamp format to 24 hours timestamp format in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

how to convert 12 hours timestamp format  to 24 hours timestamp format in postgres? like '2016-07-01 01:12:22 PM' to '2016-07-01 13:12:22'

Comment: Is this for display?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: yes for display @Used_By_Already

Comment: datatype is timestamp without timezone @http://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name

Answer (score 15):

#### Using PostgreSQL:

To convert 24 hours to 12 hours:

```
select to_char( to_timestamp ( '13:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS' ) , 'HH12:MI:SS PM' )
    from emp_table;
```

To convert 12 hours to 24 hours:

```
select to_char( to_timestamp ( '11:00:00' , 'HH12:MI:SS' ) , 'HH24:MI:SS AM' )
    from emp_table;
```

Comment: i would accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Values in a `timestamp` (or `date`, `time`, `integer` or any type non-character type) are not stored in any specific format.

Any format you *see* is applied by the application you are using to *display* the values - typically the SQL client you are using.

There are two ways to change that:

1. Configure your SQL client to use a different timestamp format for display (how you do that depends on the SQL client you are using - check its manual)
2. Use the `the_char()` function to format your timestamp value throug SQL

   ```
   select to_char(the_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
   from the_table
   ```

More details on the available formats can be found in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Easily, just cast it like follows:

```
SELECT '2016-07-01 01:12:22 PM'::timestamp;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2016-07-01 13:12:22
(1 row)
```

Comment: but actually i am facing problem while this stiring format '04-JAN-16 04.01.26.000000000 PM' to  '2016-01-04 16:01:26' format. @http://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name

Comment: but actually i am facing problem while this stiring format '04-JAN-16 04.01.26.000000000 PM' to '2016-01-04 16:01:26' format.     @http://stackoverflow.com/users/6723862/kristo-m%c3%a4gi

Comment: A lazy way using native Postgres function could be then: `SELECT replace( replace( '04-JAN-16 04:01:26.000000000 PM', '.000000000', '' ), '.', ':' )::timestamp;`. Basically, you need to only replace dot with colon except for milliseconds. But in case you have MS only full of zeros then I simply removed it. Hopefully helps :)